# throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging on my console..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Created a PrivateRoute for dashboard page that isn't accessible from URL without signing in first but refreshing the dashboard page causes the redirect to auth page. So, I've added a sessionStorage but now on refreshing its showing "throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging" on my console as it is redirecting on the page again and again non-stop.

//Here's the code

//App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard";
import Auth from "./components/auth";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/signin" element={<Auth />} />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard"
          element={<PrivateRoute> <Dashboard /></PrivateRoute>}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//PrivateRoute.js

```
import {  Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth } from "./config/firebase";

function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  // Check if the user is authenticated
  if (!user) {
    // User is not authenticated, redirect to the sign-in page
    return <Navigate to="/signin" replace/>;
  }

  // User is authenticated, render the protected route
  return children;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

//Auth.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth, googleProvider } from "../config/firebase";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut,
} from "firebase/auth";

function Auth ()  {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  console.log(auth?.currentUser?.email);

  useEffect(()=> {
    const userFromStorage = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
    if(userFromStorage){
      console.log(userFromStorage);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
  } , [navigate]);

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      sessionStorage.setItem("user" , JSON.stringify(auth.currentUser));
      navigate("/dashboard");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
      sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(auth.currentUser));
      navigate("./dashboard");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const Logout = async () => {
    try {
      await signOut(auth);
      sessionStorage.removeItem("user");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input placeholder="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="password"
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={signIn}>sign in</button>
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>sign in with Google</button>
      <button onClick={Logout}>Logout</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Auth;
```

Don't want this error and as I'm a Beginner, if there's a room for improvement feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the authentication state asynchronously.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from './config/firebase';

function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Observe user auth changes
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    // Unsubscribe when component is unmounted
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>; // Optional loading indicator

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/signin" replace />;
  }

  return children;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```